# Math Symbol Horizontal Alignment

Tags: fonts, vertical-alignment, unicode-math

I'm now using `TeX Gyre Pagella` for text and `TeX Gyre Pagella Math` for math, with `unicode-math` package. But it seems that the math symbols are not in correct positions, compared with letters or numbers near them.

For example the plus-minus sign here: 
[image: misaligned \pm sign]

Here's a MWE

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{leftidx}
\usepackage[math-style=TeX]{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[BoldFont=TeX Gyre Pagella Bold,ItalicFont=TeX Gyre Pagella Italic, BoldItalicFont=TeX Gyre Pagella Bold Italic]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
r=-1\pm i
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

There's another post saying that not to use `unicode-math`. But so far I can't find other ways without this package. So are there any solutions based on this MWE? If not, please also provide a possible solution that doesn't change my typefonts.

Comment: IMHO they are in the _right_ position.

Comment: @JouleV it should be noted that with the Computer Modern font the ± symbol is on the baseline and not below it.